# Do Elves ever forget a murder?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I murdered one of the Thalmor guards at the Jarl's place in Markarth. Slit his throat. It was an act of hatred, I admit. After the murder the two other elves went searching, didn't see me and returned to pacing around as usual. I got no bounty on me.

Now, whenever they see me they attack, causing the humans to attack me as well. Guards and other citizens are not hostile and do not attack me if the elves do not first. The only thing that threw me off was that I entered Nepos' house (for Forsworn Conspiracy) and got attacked right away.

Question: Would it solve this problem to stay away from Markarth for several days? Or should I just murder the other two Altmer? Is there any other way to solve this, without loading a previous save? Because that one is kinda far back...

Comment: I can comment here as the same happened to me. Can't remember the quest I completed in Markarth now, but for ages the guards would come attacking me accusing me of murder (Which was probably justified). I kept clear for a week or two of playing - and now all seems fine.

Comment: well, the guards do nothing in my case. no bounty, nothing. they behave like nothing happened. its just the elves that attack me on sight.

Comment: I've often found more murder to be the best solution. In this case, murder the other two Thalmor -- problem solved! Why you didn't do that in the first place is beyond me...

No idea if it'll actually fix your problem, but at least it'll feel good, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to do that. Murder all Altmer I meet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I traveled back to Whiterun, slept there for 24h then went back to Markarth. Now the elves aren't hostile. That amout of time was enough, appearantely.  The murdered guard hasn't respawned. Looks like its possible to get rid of the elves in the Underkeep.
Probbably gonna do that, for RP reasons.

Comment: +1 for role-playing a character who seems like a delight at social gatherings.